# Pointing to an array created using std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, header

I am trying to make a pointer to an array of doubles declared with array.h, but I can't get it to work. If I use the built-in double array it works fine, but I want to know if there is a way to point to the address of an array declared this way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    using std::array;

    array <double, 3> dashTimes; 

    double *pr;

   pr = dashTimes;

   return 0;
}
```

edit: I sloppily wrote this while at work from a bigger problem. Sorry for any obvious mistakes.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. As I mentioned in my question, I want to know if there is a way to create a pointer for an array created with the format <i> array <typeName, n> arrName </i>

Comment: It's fun to read the documentation rather than guessing mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a pointer to the *data* held by the array. You can get a pointer to the first element thus:

```
double* pr = dashTimes.data();
```

or

```
double* pr = &dashTimes[0];
```

If you really want a pointer to the array, then

```
array <double, 3>* pr = dashTimes;
```

but that seems unlikely as it isn't very useful.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!